# Converting SQL query into elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

Anyone able to tell me the easiest way to map this SQL query into a Elastic search query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.ProductSearches AS PS
WHERE PS.ProductId = 'SOME_PRODUCT_ID'
AND PS.SearchDate >= 'CURRENT_DATE (NOW)'
AND PS.SearchDate < 'PASTE_DATE (Ex: 2014-01-02)'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you actually want to query in the range `[2014-01-02 TO now]` - because your initial SQL is doing it vise versa.

Nevertheless it should look like:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/ProductSearches/_search -d '
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "ProductId": "${productId}" }},
        { "range" : {
            "SearchDate" : {
              "gte": "${pasteDate}",
              "lte": "now"
            }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

The resulting JSON will contain `hits.total` field which will be semantically equal to `count(*)`.